# Why isn't this instance being removed from my list of objects?

Tags: python, class, loops, oop, methods

So I have created 2 classes called Invitation and Response. Then, I created a class called Event. Within the Event class, I have to create function that looks at the current list of invites and list of responses and counts how many invites have no response.

The invites and the responses both have a "name" attribute that I use in my get_pending() method.

I have a class instance called "e" that looks as follows:

```
e = Event("graduation",[Invitation("A",5),Invitation("B",10),Invitation("C",5),Invitation("D",7)], [Response("A",True,5),Response("B",True,6),Response("C",False,0),Response("D",True,1)])
```

I then print the class method get_pending:

```
print(e.count_pending())
```

Here is my code with the get_pending() method:

```
class Invitation:
    def __init__(self, name, num_invited):
        self.name = name #str
        self.num_invited = num_invited #positive int
    def __str__(self):
        return ("Invitation('%s', %i)" % (self.name, self.num_invited))
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.name == other.name and self.num_invited == other.num_invited:
            return True
    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.name < other.name:
            return True
        elif self.name == other.name:
            if self.num_invited < other.num_invited:
                return True
class Response:
    def __init__(self, name, ans, num_attending):
        self.name = name #str
        self.ans = ans #bool - T/F
        self.num_attending = num_attending #zero or more people
    def __str__(self):
        return ("Response('%s', %r, %i)" % (self.name, self.ans, self.num_attending))
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.name == other.name and self.ans == other.ans and self.num_attending == other.num_attending:
            return True
    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.name < other.name:
            return True
        elif self.name == other.name:
            if self.ans < other.ans:
                return True
            elif self.ans == other.ans:
                if self.num_attending < other.num_attending:
                    return True
class Event:
    def __init__(self, title, invites=None, responses=None):
        self.title = title #str
        self.invites = invites #list
        self.responses = responses #list
        if self.invites == None:
            self.invites = []
        if self.responses == None:
            self.responses = []
        self.invites.sort()
        self.responses.sort()
    def __str__(self):
        return ("""Event('%s', %r, %r)""" % (self.title, self.invites, self.responses))
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.title == other.title and self.invites == other.invites and self.responses == other.responses:
            return True
    def count_pending(self):
        num_pending = 0
        lst_noresp = self.invites[:]
        for invi in lst_noresp:
            if (any(invi.name == resp.name for resp in self.responses)) == True:
                lst_noresp.remove(invi)
        for invi in lst_noresp:
            num_pending += invi.num_invited
        return num_pending

e = Event("graduation",[Invitation("A",5),Invitation("B",10),Invitation("C",5),Invitation("D",7)], [Response("A",True,5),Response("B",True,6),Response("C",False,0),Response("D",True,1)])
print(e.count_pending())
```

**My error is that the count_pending() method is only removing some (Invite with name 'A' and Invite with name 'C') objects from the invite list even though all invites have a corresponding response. Why isn't the invi.name == resp.name comparison working properly? Or, is that even the issue?**

Comment: A few `print`s for debugging may be helpful, especially a `print(invi)` directly before or after `lst_noresp.remove(invi)` to see if the `if` works correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I will update the code to reflect that and post back here if any issue is exposed.

Comment: @MichaelButscher So I have noticed that the line that says "if (any(invi.name == resp.name for resp in self.responses)) == True:" results in a generator exit for the second and fourth invites but not for the first and 3rd invites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the classic problem of mutating a `list` while iterating it here:

```
    for invi in lst_noresp:  # Iterating
        if (any(invi.name == resp.name for resp in self.responses)) == True:
            lst_noresp.remove(invi)  # Mutating
```

While there is no documented behavior for it, in practice, this causes the loop to skip the value following each removed element (the iterator stores the current index, and the `remove` shifts the following elements down, so when you get the next element, you've bypassed the element that was shifted into the space occupied by the removed element), so you're not even checking half your values. Iterate over `self.invites`, and mutate `lst_noresp`, and the problem should disappear.

Alternatively, construct a new `list` and avoid `O(n**2)` performance:

```
    lst_noresp = [invi for invi in self.invites 
                  if not any(invi.name == resp.name for resp in self.responses)]
```

which avoids slow removals from the middle of a `list` in favor of filtering during construction of a new `list` (`O(n)` work).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! Would another way to solve the issue (which I am more used to) is rather than removing invites that already exist in responses, could I simply append any invites that don't have a response to a new list and iterate over that list?

Comment: @ruckarucka: Heh. I was just adding that approach when you commented. Yeah, it's generally simpler and more efficient to do it that way, see the example code.

Comment: Yeah I completely agree, thank you for the updated code.